# extrude loop cut

Tags: modeling, extrude

Following this great [tutorial on Youtube on min: 36:50](https://youtu.be/CmBMcYVW9x8?t=2210)

Trying to extrude a loop cut to create a roof but it extrudes the line as plane
not sure what I am missing, also the gizmo is missing.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the tutorial he doesn't extrude, he just translates it.  Instead of hitting <kbd>E</kbd>  to extrude, just hit <kbd>G</kbd> to grab, then <kbd>Z</kbd> to limit it to the $Z$ axis.

Or you can always click the icon for *Move*, which is the third one down on the left, then use the vertical blue Z axis arrow to move those vertices.

Answer (score 0):

ok
got it (:
its not extrude its move command!
Thank you

Comment: Hello :). Please mark the answer form @Vega as accepted **✓**, if it helped. Thanks for keeping this site nice and tidy :).